# Sync Google Chrome installed manually (not through official channels)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

It seems that the extensions I install in Chrome directly from the .crx file don't ever get synced to my other computers. Is this because they did not come from the official channels (Chrome Web Store or Chrome Extensions)?

Is there any way to get such manually-installed extensions to sync?

Comment: Doubt it. They probably have some opposition to uploading programs.

Answer (score 0):

Possible option, if you don't mind the quirkiness of it, is to run [Google Chrome Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable) from within Dropbox.